# Expansion in differential equation (rapid oscillating field)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, oscillators

Can anyone explain me how to derive the equation in (30.4)? I don't understand what approximations or substitutions are exactly performed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do a first order Taylor expansion in powers of $\xi$ around $x=X$, where $\xi=x-X$.

You might be familiar with the Taylor expansion of a function $g(x)$ around $x=x_0$:

$g(x) = g(x_0) + \frac{dg(x)}{dx} (x-x_0)+ \frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2g(x)}{dx^2} (x-x_0)^2 + ...$

Here 
$g(x)=-\frac{dU}{dx}+f$ and $\xi=x-x_0$ and $X=x_0$. They only use the first term in the expansion.

Comment: I was just writing the same. Still, it's odd that they have $\frac{\mathrm d U}{\mathrm d x}$ instead of $\frac{\mathrm d U}{\mathrm d X}$.

Comment: Thank you both. That's what I thought, but as @Sten pointed out, the diff. by $x$ instead of $X$ confused me.